# Webpack - request to database and replace string in bundle

Tags: webpack

I currently use Webpack 4 and I want to replace a string with a specific pattern to string from the database.

For example GET from the database return:

```
[{ key: 'test', value: TEST2 }]
```

so If webpack find any string 'test' - it will replace to TEST2.

**I need:**

1. Build bundle
2. Connect to the database by npm plugin
3. GET data as an array with key and value
4. Replace all keys in the bundle to values

Do you have any idea how should I do it? I don't know how it will work with async request and webpack build. What plugins will be the best?

**EDIT:**
I used npm library to handle connection with the database with promises. So firstly I created Promise where is resolved with config after a successful response, otherwise, I reject it. This promise should be put in module.exports.
To replace strings in bundle we can use string-replace-loader plugin and add it to rules in webpack config (we can create in database query promise array and use it in config)

```
const config = { ... }; // some webpack config
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql.connect(...some sql config...)
        .then(() => {
            sql.query(...some sql query..)
                .then((response) => {
                    // here we can for example, modify config basing on 
                    // response (but firstly change it from const to let)
                    resolve(config);
                })
                .catch(() => reject());
        })
        .catch(() => reject());
});

module.exports = promise;
```